# How to get referenced objects from XAML Code after loading it with XamlReder.Load?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to use XAML code to serialise object structure with XamlWriter and also to have possibility that XAML code again with XamlReader to load back in Object structure. Output XAML Code should be readable so that person can edit it(or write new one) and should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MainClass>   
    <Class2 Name="Calss2Name">
        <Class3 Name="Class3Name">
        </Class3>
    </Class2>
    <!-- Where Class2Name is reference to Class2 tag and after loading into Object structure Class1 schould have a reference set to Class2-->
    <Class1 Class2Property="Calss2Name" />
</MainClass>
```

and Class structure should look like this:

```
   public class MainClass
   {
        public MainClass()
        {
            _class2ListProperty = new List<Class2>();
            _class1ListProperty = new List<Class1>();
        }

        private List<Class2> _class2ListProperty = new List<Class2>();
        private List<Class1> _class1ListProperty = new List<Class1>();

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<Class2> Class2ListProperty 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _class2ListProperty;
            }
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<Class1> Class1ListProperty 
        {
            get
            {
                return _class1ListProperty;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        private Class2 _class2Member;

        public String Name { get; set; }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public Class2 Class2Property 
        {
            get
            {
                return _class2Member;
            }
            set 
            {
                this._class2Member = value;
            } 
        }
    }


    public class Class2
    {
        public Class2()
        {
            _class3ListMember = new List<Class3>();
        }

        private List<Class3> _class3ListMember = new List<Class3>();

        public String Name { get; set; }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<Class3> Class3ListProperty 
        {
            get 
            { 
                return _class3ListMember; 
            }
        }
    }

    public class Class3
    {
        public Class3()
        {
            _class3ListMember = new List<Class3>();
        }

        public String Name { get; set; }

        [TypeConverter(typeof(Int32RangeConverter))]
        public Int32Range Runtime { get; set; }

        private List<Class3> _class3ListMember = new List<Class3>();

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<Class3> Class3ListProperty 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return _class3ListMember; 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Is it posssible to build such structure boht for XAML File and for Classes without putting whole Class2 node once more in Class1 tree? When yes, I will appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bro, DON'T USE XAML for this propose! I tried to do somthing like this and got many-many troubles after.
Use xml or json!

Comment: What kind of troubles?

Comment: What you are looking for is serialization. take a look here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For example:
1. Xaml-reader isn't tolerant for changes. So add/remove fields to your classes is the problem.
2. Xaml-reader produced unclear error messages. So find an error in files is the problem.

Comment: 3. Xaml-reader is very hard to extend. So if required structure migration -- for example remove one field but add another base on previous value -- is the problem

Comment: Class-structure should stay constant, the only thing that should be changed is content of XAML File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it working! Using MarkupExtension I could reference Property to correspondig object. So, Xaml code should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MainClass>   
    <Class2 Name="Calss2Name">
        <Class3 Name="Class3Name">
        </Class3>
    </Class2>
    <!-- Where Class2Name is reference to Class2 tag and after loading into Object structure Class1 schould have a reference set to Class2-->
    <Class1 Class2Property="{Class2MarkupExtension class2Name=Calss2Name}" />
</MainClass>
```

and I have to implement Class2MarkupExtension Class which inherit class MarkupExtension:

```
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Class2))]
    public class Class2MarkupExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        #region Properties

        [ConstructorArgument("class2Name")]
        public String Class2Name { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public Class2MarkupExtension()
        {

        }

        public Class2MarkupExtension(String class2Name)
        {
            Class2Name = class2Name;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            Type providerType = provider.GetType();

            ///Get _xamlContext member from provider.
            FieldInfo fieldsInfo = providerType.GetField("_xamlContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);            
            object parserContex = fieldsInfo.GetValue(provider);

            ///Get _rootInstance member from _xamlContext member.
            providerType = parserContex.GetType();
            fieldsInfo = providerType.GetField("_rootInstance", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);

            Class2 class2 = null;
            MainClass rootElement = (MainClass)fieldsInfo.GetValue(parserContex);
            if (rootElement.Class2ListProperty  != null && rootElement.Class2ListProperty.Count > 0)
            {
                class2 = rootElement.Class2ListProperty .Where(s => s.Name.Equals(Class2Name)).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (scenario == null)
            {
                class2 = new Class2() { Name = Class2Name };
            }
            return class2;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

further I've created LoadMainClass method which converts Xaml into Object structure:

```
public class MainClassFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns MainClass Object from Xaml Code.
    /// </summary>
    public static MainClass LoadMainClass(String xamlAsString)
    {
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlAsString.ToString());

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        object outputMainClass = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

        return outputMainClass as MainClass;
    }
}
```

This is solution which works on .Net Framework 3.5 for .Net Framework 4+ is slightly different, you don't have to use reflection to get _rootInstance field just have to do this:

```
IRootObjectProvider rootProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
```